# SharePoint Online with Excel 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

We have started using SharePoint Online. One of our users is trying to make a basic task - edit an Excel file that stored on SharePoint Online.

Steps he performs:

1. Check out the file
2. Open in Excel (not online)
3. File opened in read only mode even when he trying to click "Edit workbook" is still in read-only and he need to save it with a different file name.

What are we missing?

Comment: It sounds a bit like the user has edit permissions for the file, but doesn't have permission which allow adding to the file's location.

Comment: the user have an admin permission on the folder

Comment: What is the file extension? (.xls or .xlsx)

Comment: it seems that Microsoft has a globally sharepoint problem. and of course they didn't notice users via status page or health page of O365. half a day burned on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check-out the file before editing. You can directly open the file in either Excel online or local Excel client. When you start editing the file it will get checked-out automatically and when you close it will get check-in.

If you have versioning enabled then you have to publish changes in order to check-in the file.